# Python: WinError 10045: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Tags: python, client-server

I'm creating a Caesar Cipher program using a client/server program. The client will enter a message and a key and the server will return the cipher text. This is my server code:

```
import socket

def getCaesar(message, key):
    cipher = "" 

    for i in message: 
        char = message[i] 

        # Encrypt uppercase characters 
        if (char.isupper()): 
            cipher += chr((ord(char) + key-65) % 26 + 65) 

        # Encrypt lowercase characters 
        else: 
            cipher += chr((ord(char) + key - 97) % 26 + 97) 

    return cipher 

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=socket.gethostname()
port=4000

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
print("Listenting for requests")

while True:
    s,addr=s.accept()
    print("Got connection from ",addr)
    print("Receiving...")

    message,key=s.recv(1024)
    resp=getCaesar(message, key)

    s.send(resp)
s.close()
```

The error message calls this line out: s.send(message, key) with this error:

OSError: [WinError 10045] The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced. What does this error mean?

My client code:

```
import socket

def getMessage():
    print('Enter your message:')
    return input()

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the key number (1-%s)' % (26))
        key = int(input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= 26):
            return key

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host=socket.gethostname()
port=4000
s.connect((host,port))


message = getMessage()
key = getKey()

message=message.encode()


s.send(message, key)
cipher= s.recv(1024)

print('Ciphertext: ')
print(cipher)
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See help(socket.send):

```
Help on built-in function send:

send(...) method of socket.socket instance
    send(data[, flags]) -> count

    Send a data string to the socket.  For the optional flags
    argument, see the Unix manual.  Return the number of bytes
    sent; this may be less than len(data) if the network is busy.
```

So, the line `s.send(message, key)` may work not the way you expected: its sends only the `message` with `key` interpreted as flags, not both `message` and `key`. Try to send `message` and `key` separately. And dont forget to `recv` them separately too.